# VB ASP.NET Web Application Properties Created as a Class Library?

Tags: vb.net

I just noticed that when creating a new ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) then choosing Empty Project" it is created with an Application Type of "Class Library".  As I am migrating some old Web Sites into the newer version, is there a reason it is recognized as "Class Library" as opposed to an empty web site or simply stating the framework?

[image: Class Library As Web Application]

Comment: A web application and a web site are two different things.  A web site is not compiled whereas a web application is.  As such, a web application needs a target assembly type to be compiled to. If you don't want it compiled to a DLL then you can change that selection, but be sure you know what you're doing in that case. I guess the question is why you chose Empty Project in the first place. If you're creating a web application then presumably you want it to be Web Forms, MVC or SPA, so why not choose one of those options?

Comment: The original wasn't an MVC or SPA project so the alternative was Web Forms ... I went with Empty Project for bare bones because it seemed to have extra bloat references that I didn't need.  So rather than deleting, I figured build up from Empty since it was a migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your confusion might arise because ASP.NET "Web Sites" are a special exception to the normal rule of how .NET programs work.  In an ASP.NET Web Site, you put all the files you work with (`.aspx`, `.vb`, `.ascx`, etc) directly on the server when you finish with them and *that's it*.  The server auto*magically* figures out how to connect the source code files with the website pages as the website runs.  There's a *lot* of assumptions and limitations involved in this process.

On the other hand, ASP.NET Web Applications are standard .NET applications.  Like other standard applications, your source code files (`.vb`) are compiled into a single file containing all of your program code in an format that your computer knows how to run.  Now the server just has to "run" your program.  No automatically connecting source code files and website pages.  No assumptions. 
 No magic.

A bit more about why your program is specifically a "Class Library" - there are three different ways the computer knows how to run your program.  They correspond to the three options for Application type in your project properties.

1. Most programs open with a normal GUI.  They have buttons, title bars, menus, etc.  This is called a "Windows Application".
2. Some programs - usually more technical programs - only support keyboard input/output.  They run in a command shell.  This is called a "Console Application".
3. Some programs cannot be run directly at all.  Instead, they provide a 
   library of functions for *other programs* to use.  This is called a "Class Library" or a DLL.

An ASP.NET Web Application doesn't run all by itself.  Instead, it's "hosted" by a server (normally IIS).  The web application is a "library" with all the code needed to run your specific application.  The server opens your library and actually executes the web application.

Comment: As this is the first time using the newer version and now I see that the "From" project version is under Previous Versions in VS2017, what are the variables (no coding pun intended) I should look out && account for when migrating? (Not an MVC nor SPA project && I'm migrating due to the limited MSBuild support for the Web Site) ...also thank you so much for your answer it was very helpful